# Passing arguments to rake task from model not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer, rake-task

I am trying to call a rake task to send an email to a list of subscribers from a controller action like so:

Controller action:

```
def send_digest
   @article_ids = params[:article_ids]
   @subject = params[:subject]
   EmailDigest.send_email_digest("weekly_digest_task", @article_ids, @subject)

   redirect_to new_digests_path
end
```

email_digest.rb:

```
require 'rake'

class EmailDigest < ActiveRecord::Base

  def self.send_email_digest(weekly_digest_task, article_ids, subject)
    load File.join(Rails.root, 'lib', 'tasks', 'send_email_digest.rake')
    Rake::Task['weekly_digest_task'].invoke("\\\"#{article_ids}\\\"","\\\"#{subject}\\\"")
  end

end
```

And here is the send_email_digest.rake:

```
task :weekly_digest_task, [:article_ids,:subject] => :environment do |task, args|

  articles = args.article_ids
  subject = args.subject
  article_objects = []

  articles.each do |m|
    article_objects << Article.find_by_id(m)
  end

  EmailDigest.all.each do |subscriber|
    DigestMailer.weekly_digest(subscriber, article_objects, subject).deliver
  end

end
```

The redirect occurs and I am taken to that page with no errors, however no emails get sent. As such, I have no idea why this is not working.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a string to your task, so unless you extract the array of ids back from the string, you are essentially enumerating over the string rather than the items. I would like to know what version of ruby you are using because in 1.9+ string is no longer an enumerable and so you should be getting an error.

However all this is not necessary because you can directly pass an array to invoke.

Your code is also unnecessarily convoluted. Especially it is not advisable to `load` file from within a method (as it will cause the file contents to be evaluated on each invocation of the method). It could easily be `require`d at the top.

Ideally, it would be an better if you move the logic from rake task to a method in the model or a mediator and just call that from both the rake task as well as the mailer.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. Even when I pass an array into invoke, it seems that the code in the task is still not run.

Comment: If anyone reads this, I abandoned the above solution and integrated sidekiq to run this as a background job instead of a rake task.